# List files after upload

Tags: javascript, plupload

I am probably overlooking something in the docs, but I cannot seem to figure out how to generate a list of files that were uploaded using the plupload script from (http://www.plupload.com)

I am pretty sure that the event that I need to add the code to is the UploadComplete event (shown below) but not sure what I need to add to this event to list the files so if anyone could lend a hand here that would be great.

```
UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
 // what needs to go here to list the files that were uploaded. 
},
```

BTW, I already tried the obvious solution which was alert(files) but that returns [object Object] which is not what I am looking for so how does this need to be formatted to display the files names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make this work. Albeit not exactly how I wanted it to, but it will do in the meantime.

Basically all I did was create a textarea that is hidden when the page first loads and then I used the `FileUploaded` event to append the name of each file to the textarea after it has been successfully uploaded.

After all the files have been uploaded the `UploadComplete` event is automatically triggered so all I needed to do at that point was to tell the event to show the previously hidden textarea and all the names of the files were there as I needed them to be.

As I said this is not the way I imagined this working out and I still am not sure why I cannot access the file names from the `UploadComplete` event itself, but this will do for now and thx again to Nike for his reply.

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, right?
add a console.log(files) call and examine the contents in Firebug.

Comment: Yes in JS and I updated my question to show the what using "files" returns which is [object Object] and not the file name(s) that I need.

Comment: Try in Firebug, it allows you to expand the Object.

Comment: Tried that and I get the following params: id, loaded, name, percent, size, & status so I tried instead to do alert(files.name) but no go. I get undefined so any other suggestions ?